# get ids of uploads and pass to controller, codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

Does anyone know how I can get the just uploaded images ids and access the array of them from my controller?

My model: http://pastebin.com/aJW0vq22 (do_upload())

And here's the relevant part of my controller:
class Site extends CI_Controller {

```
function index() {
    //enable profiler
    //$this->output->enable_profiler(TRUE);

    $data = array();
    $this->load->model('Site_model');

    if($this->input->post('upload')) {

        $data['upload'] = $this->Site_model->do_upload();
        //echo '<hr />' . $this->Site_model->total_uploads;
        //set the users edit session for their image
        $uploaded_image_id = $this->Site_model->get_last();

        $values = array(
        'image_id' => $uploaded_image_id,
        'session_id' => $this->session->set_userdata('session_id')
        );
        $this->session->set_userdata('edit', $values);
        //var_dump($values);

        //show uploaded image
        redirect($uploaded_image_id . '?links');

    }
```

Currently I've just been using 'get_last()' to just get the last thing added to the database, but now I've added the ability to upload multiple things at once I doubt I can still, any ideas?

edit:

basically the end result i'm trying to get is

```
        redirect('id1, id2, id3' . '?links');
```

Answer (score 0):

You could save the file names of the just uploaded images into a session array and then query your database for the ids of those file names. This will reliably return the desierd ids.

I see that for your get_last you use a query that returns the last image added to the table. But what if you have 500 users uploading an image at the same time?

Comment: here's what i ended up doing, im not sure what would happen with uploads at the same time, within do_upload() http://pastebin.com/rXDCmfyn

Comment: The solution is still flaky. Think of it this way, you want some specific image ids from the database, you ask your function get_last() to return the latest uploaded and you hope that the latest uploaded is the one you are expecting but that may not always be the case. Instead, try to transform get_last into something like this get_last(array('image_name_in_db_1.png', 'image_name_in_db_2.png')) { ... SELECT id FROM images WHERE image_name = 'image_name_in_db_1.png' ... }